# Execute Python requests inside while loop without interrupting or slowing the loop

Tags: python, json, while-loop, get

I'm trying to make a while loop statement that will fetch data from the internet let's say a status and will run the loop depending on the status posted to the system.

Currently I was able to fetch data from the internet and identify the status by parsing it into a JSON format. What i want to do is to execute a loop if the status is equal to 0 and consistently check for the status without interrupting or slowing down the loop. (I mean I want the loop to run continuously without interruption even for a second).

Here's the current code i'm working with to fetch data from the server and use as a triggering point of the loop.

```
def movement(status):
    print('movement_oaaut')
    r1 = requests.get('http://aviarthardph.net/robot/table.php?tableInfo')
    data1 = r1.json()
    print(data1['status'])
    while(data1['status'] == '0' or data1['status'] == 0):
    print('galaw')
    print ('movement_in')
      while m.farTrack() == '1101':
        print ("Left")
        myData = ""
        m.left(0.1)
        break
      while m.farTrack() == '1011':
        print ("Right")
        myData = ""
        m.right(0.1)
        break 
      while m.farTrack() == '1110':
        print ("Right")
        myData = ""
        m.right(0.1)
        break 
      while m.farTrack() == '0111':
        print ("Left")
        myData = ""
        m.left(0.1)
        break 
      while m.farTrack() == '0011':
        print ("Left")
        myData = ""
        m.left(0.1)
        break
      while m.farTrack() == '1100':
        print ("Right")
        myData = ""
        m.right(0.1)
        break
      while m.farTrack() == '0110':
        print ("Right")
        myData = ""
        m.right(0.1)
        break
      while m.farTrack() == '0010':
        print ("Right")
        myData = ""
        m.right(0.1)
        break
      while m.farTrack() == '1111':#if counter
        print ("Left")
        myData = ""
        m.left(0.1)
        break
      while m.lineTrack() == '1110':
        print ("Right")
        myData = ""
        m.right(0.1)
        break
```

I already tried adding new requests inside the while loop like this one.

```
def movement(status):
print('movement_oaaut')
r1 = requests.get('http://aviarthardph.net/robot/table.php?tableInfo')
data1 = r1.json()
print(data1['status'])
while(data1['status'] == '0' or data1['status'] == 0):
print('galaw')
print ('movement_in')
  while m.farTrack() == '1101':
    print ("Left")
    myData = ""
    m.left(0.1)
    break
    r1 = requests.get('http://aviarthardph.net/robot/table.php?tableInfo')
    data1 = r1.json()
```

But whenever I run the loop there's a 2 seconds delay. Like what I said, I want the loop to continuously running without a delay of even 1 second and fetch status in the internet at the same time.

I'm a beginner to Python.

Comment: requests.get() is a syncronous command, so the delay may be out of your control because it entirely depends on the web server on the other end.  additionally bear in mind some servers implement rate throttling to prevent too many requests occurring from the same client.

Comment: is there any possible way to run the get like in the background outside the loop that will fetch data continuously?